# getting highest value in files and storing the next values as per desired count

Tags: bash

let us say i have counter, which is variable. For clarity, `counter = 3`.

And I have files with different values:

file 1

```
3
4
8
```

file 2

```
2
3
4
5
```

file 3

```
11
13
15
```

file 4

```
19
29
34
```

my desired output is a variable `max= 34` need to be printed.

Also based on `count=3`, in this case I should able to store next values in variables

```
variable A= 35
variable B =36
variable C =37
```

and print them.

I tried different codes with `if -> then` etc, but nothing coming closer.

can someone give me pointers?

This was the code i last tried

```
f1mx = `cat file1 | grep "." | tail -1`
f2mx = `cat file2 | grep "." | tail -1`
f3mx = `cat file3 | grep "." | tail -1`
f4mx = `cat file4 | grep "." | tail -1`

if [ $f1mx \> $f2mx ];
then 
    f12mx=$f1mx
else 
    f12mx=$f2mx;
fi;

if [ $f3mx \> $f4mx ];
then 
    f34mx=$f3mx
else 
    f34mx=$f4mx;
fi;

if [ $f12mx \> $f34mx ];
then 
    fmax=$f12mx
else 
    fmax=$f34mx
fi;

echo "fmax"

i=0
while [  $i -le $counter ]; 
do
    a[$i]=$fmax+1
    echo $a[$i];
    let i=i+1 
done
```

Comment: Since you mention that you have tried different codes but which doesn't work, I would suggest to [edit] the question to include what you have tried. And see [editing-help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to format your post properly.

Comment: f1mx = `cat file1 | grep "." | tail -1`
f2mx = `cat file2 | grep "." | tail -1`
f3mx = `cat file3 | grep "." | tail -1`
f4mx = `cat file4 | grep "." | tail -1`

if [ $f1mx \> $f2mx ];

then 

f12mx=$f1mx

else 

f12mx=$f2mx;

fi;

if [ $f3mx \> $f4mx ];

then 

f34mx=$f3mx

else 

f34mx=$f4mx;

fi;

if [ $f12mx \> $f34mx ];

then 

fmax=$f12mx

else 

fmax=$f34mx

fi;

echo "fmax"

i=0
       
while [  $i -le $counter ]; 

do

a[$i]=$fmax+1
echo $a[$i];

let i=i+1 

done

Comment: @user261334 edit your post and format it properly. I guess it is obvious how difficult to read it is now.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing all the files with name `file*` in your directory are the ones having these values, you can get the maximum value like this:

```
$ cat f* | sort -n | tail -1
34
```

Or store it:

```
$ max=$(cat f* | sort -n | tail -1)
$ echo $max
34
```

To define variables based on this value, do:

```
for i in $(seq $count)
do
    declare v$i=$((max + $i))
done
```

This will generate from `v1` up to `v$count` (`$v3`) in your case, being each one like `v_i = $max + $i`.

Comment: +1 good answer. I'd use an array myself: `v=( $((max+1)) $((max+2)) $((max+3)) )` but the OP asked for vars.